# Express & connect-busboy ignore from some requests

Tags: node.js, express, busboy

I use connect-busboy with express:

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(busboy());
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
        res.send(500, 'error');
    });
```

and with the following request:

```
app.post('/save', function (req, res) { 
       console.log("Got request")
         try {
         console.log("I got it");
         req.pipe(req.busboy);
         var name = "";
         var start = "";
         var fstream;
        req.busboy.on('field', function (fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) { }


        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file) {
           //some code
        }

        req.busboy.on('error', function (error) {
                console.log("Error in uploading file with chunks: "  + error);
            // some code
         })
        req.busboy.on('finish', function () {
               fstream.on('close', function(){
                       //some code
    })
})
```

the client send me 6 request for save command. I get inconsistently 2-6 requests.

Meaning, `Got request` is printed only 2 times, but the client send 6 times the request.

When I delete the `app.use(busboy());` line, `Express.app` get the 6 request (but I can't use the function because the `req.busboy.on` doesn't work).

The conclusion is that `app.use(busboy());` ignore some requests from the client, and the `app.post` isn't fired. How can I solve it?

Comment: connect-busboy doesn't end any requests, it just calls `next()` to go to the next middleware/route. The [source code](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy/blob/master/index.js) is quite simple.

Comment: @mscdex: So why is it happens?

Comment: All I can say is the problem doesn't lie in any of the code you've posted so far.

Comment: @mscdex: But when I delete the `app.use(busboy());` line, I success to get all the request.

Comment: Try replacing `app.use(busboy());` with `app.use(function(req,res,next){next();});`

Comment: but I use req.busboy.on in the request...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should do is remove `app.use(bodyParser());` because busboy is already handling body parsing.